# how to test my web application on server

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have to test what is happening in the code on the server:

```
if (impersonateValidUser(userName, domain, password)) 
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
```

like where is the code going after checking the condition

Should i use a messagebox or some other return way???

I am not sure how to do it

any help... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Weird question. If the function is defined, I would guess(or hope) it should return true or false. Whether this is true or false I guess you could determine by just printing a text in each case? `Response.Write("true")` or `Response.Write("false")`.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done by logging. Do you use any logging framework in your application such as [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html)? If not you could always write to a file by hand:

```
File.AppendAllText(Server.MapPath("~/log/myapp.txt"), "some message to write");
```